# Modification date from django-reversion

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-reversion

I used to have two date fields to save the date an object is created and modified and two foreign key fields to save who created or last modified the object.

Now I'm using `django-reversion` and I'm able to save all the users who modified the object instead of only the last person.

But how can I print the date the object was created and last modified using django-reversion instead of storing these information in the object itself?

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively straightforward using `get_for_object_reference`:

```
from reversion.revisions import default_revision_manager
item = MyModel.objects.get(some_criteria=True)
last_edit = default_revision_manager.get_for_object_reference(
        item.__class__,
        item.pk,
    ).first()

last_editor = last_edit.revision.user
date_edited = last_edit.revision.date_created
```

Comment: Can I obtain the same info in a queryset?

Comment: No, revision objects are stored elsewhere in the database. You'll need to query the database.

Comment: Would it be preferable to store creation and last modification date in the object itself instead of getting these information from the revision objects?

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't find any reference to this in the documentation.